# Migrating from Identity Toolkit to Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I had a simple node.js server that used the Firebase Admin API and the identity toolkit to generate a refresh token for a client to operate in Firebase:

1. The client makes a POST to our server with his credentials.
2. The server checks the credentials and creates a custom token with the client identifier (customToken).

   ```
   var admin = require("firebase-admin");
   ...
   admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
   ```
3. The server sends a POST request to https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken?key=API_KEY with the payload *{"returnSecureToken": true, "token": customToken}* and that returns the IdToken and the RefreshToken.
4. The servers return the IdToken and the RefreshToken to the client.
5. The client is very simple and don´t use the Firebase client SDK, and comunicates with Firebase Database with REST.(For example GET https://mydomain.firebaseio.com/x.json?auth=IdToken).
6. When the IdToken expires, the Client send a POST Request to https://securetoken.googleapis.com:443/v1/token?key=API_KEY with the payload *{"grantType" : "refresh_token", "refreshToken": RefreshToken}* and get the new IdToken.

Now I´m trying to migrate from using Identity Toolkit to Firebase Authentication and made the following changes on the server:

1. The client makes a POST to our server with his credentials.
2. The server checks the credentials and creates a custom token with the client identifier (customToken), then Sign In with the firebase client API and the custom token to get the IdToken and RefreshToken.

   ```
   var firebase = require("firebase");
   var admin = require("firebase-admin");
   ...
   admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
   .then(function (customToken) {
      firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken).then(function (usuario) {
     firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(function (IdToken) {
       console.log(IdToken);
       console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.refreshToken);
       ...
     });
     }
   );
   ```

   }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
      });
3. The servers return the IdToken and the RefreshToken to the client.
4. The client can´t use the Firebase client SDK, and comunicates with Firebase Database with REST.(For example GET https://mydomain.firebaseio.com/x.json?auth=IdToken).
5. When the IdToken expires, the Client send a POST Request to https://securetoken.googleapis.com:443/v1/token?key=API_KEY with the payload *{"grantType" : "refresh_token", "refreshToken": RefreshToken}* and get the new IdToken.

From what I understand reading the documentation, the server should only create the customTokenId and then the client, using Firebase Client SDK should sign In using that customToken, but in this case the client is so simple that don´t have the option of using the Client SDK, and only operates with REST to Firebase.

¿Is this the correct way of manage the the authentication proccess? 
¿Will be Step 5 deprecated and have problems in the future?

Comment: Why do you need to call `signInWithCustomToken` from your backend when you can just call it on the client and not deal with token refreshing, or passing ID token/refresh tokens back to the client, etc.

Comment: As I stated on the question I can´t call it on the client because I don´t have access to the client code, It´s being developed by a third party and they assure me that they don´t have the possibility of using the client API and can only access Firebase with REST request.